# Selenium : Better method to check for AJAX changes other than an infinite loop

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following code to check if a new message has arrived on Facebook Messages :

```
def waitForNextMessage():
    messageList=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.null')
    message=''
    while True:
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.null')
        if not(element == messageList):
            message=element[-1].find_elements_by_css_selector("*")[0].text
            print(message)
            break
```

Basically, at the start, I make a list of all the elements of class `.null` (the message boxes) and in an infinite loop create the list again and check if it is different. If it is, it means that a new message has arrived.

Is there a better way to do this, hopefully without an Infinite Loop?

Comment: I don't see what you're testing ? 
If you're testing that a message *is* received then you don't need the infinite loop as you can do an [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) 
If, on the other hand, you're doing some sort of continuous scrapper then the infinite loop might be what you need

Comment: It's the continuous scraper. I want to print every new message there is, and not just stop when a message is received.

Answer (score 2):

You can use explicit wait to wait for the messages `null` element to disappear

```
messageList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.null')
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.staleness_of(messageList[1]))
    message = element[1].find_elements_by_css_selector("*")[0].text
    print(message)
except TimeoutException:
    # no new message
```

This will wait up to 60 seconds for the second item in `messageList` to disappear from the DOM, i.e. you have new message. If there is new message, the code will continue to the message printing, else there will be `TimeoutException`.

> Edit

To run this for certain amount of time you can set timer

```
now = time.time()
howLong = now + 10
while time.time() < howLong:
    waitForNextMessage()
    pass
```

To run this continuously in addition to other tests you can run `waitForNextMessage()` in thread.

> Edit 2

`expected_conditions.staleness_of()` is an expectation for an element not to be attached to the DOM. You can find more expected conditions [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.staleness_of)

Comment: I want a continuous scrapper, like every time there is a new message, I want to print it, and not just wait for mere 60 seconds and stop. Also, can you explain what `stalness_of` does?